# I am getting encoded files as body in linux using mail

Tags: linux, mailx, uuencode

I am trying to send multiple files via Linux and below command worked fine on AIX but on Linux its sending encoded content in email body. Please help to understand how to send the files as attachment and decoded.  I am a noob here

`( cat Body_"$TIMESTAMP" ; /usr/bin/uuencode abc_"$TIMESTAMP" abc_123.xls ; /usr/bin/uuencode def_"$TIMESTAMP" def_123.xls ; /usr/bin/uuencode xyz_"$TIMESTAM P" xyz.xls ; /usr/bin/uuencode pqr_"$TIMESTAMP" pqr_456.xls ; /usr/bin/uuencode mno_"$TIMESTAMP" mno.xls ) | mail -s"From-To-List : ${list}" -c tommy@xyz.com team@xyz.com`

Comment: Both aix and linux use mailx for mail, but you are likely on a newer version on Linux. The docs explain how the -a switch is used to attach files and include proper mime formatting. Type `man mail` or `man mailx` at a bash command prompt to view the docs.

Comment: I tried the -a  command as well. Didnt do much but let me try in another way to see if that works